# PHP wrong database edit

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm setting up a dynamic webpage that will be used as a time stamp for employes. After you log in, you will write down when you started work, how long the break was, when you finished and so on..
Problem is that every time I wanna change something on the webpage, for example I want to change my break time, it won't change and shows me the user_id instead.
I'm still a beginner when it comes to PHP and don't know where the problem is..here are some code snippets

```
<div class="header">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <p class="text">HourBook</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th class="luecke1">Name</th>
        <th class="luecke2">Start Time</th>
        <th class="luecke3">Pause</th>
        <th class="luecke4">End Time</th>
        <th class="luecke5">Comments</th>
        <th class="luecke6">Duration</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
    $connect = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'hourbook');

    $result = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM data");
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $id = $row['id'];
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td class='luecke1'><input style='border:none; width:100%; background:rgba(0,0,0,0)' contenteditable='true' id='editor" . $id . "' value='" . $row['user_id'] . " ' onchange='pruefung({currentid:" . $id . ",currentfieldname:\"user_id\"})'></input></td>";
            echo "<td class='luecke2'><input style='border:none; width:100%; background:rgba(0,0,0,0)' contenteditable='true' id='editor" . $id . "' value='" . $row['start_time'] . " ' onchange='pruefung({currentid:" . $id . ",currentfieldname:\"start_time\"})'></input></td>";
            echo "<td class='luecke3'><input style='border:none; width:100%; background:rgba(0,0,0,0)' contenteditable='true' id='editor" . $id . "' value='" . $row['pause_time'] . " ' onchange='pruefung({currentid:" . $id . ",currentfieldname:\"pause_time\"})'></input></td>";
            echo "<td class='luecke4'><input style='border:none; width:100%; background:rgba(0,0,0,0)' contenteditable='true' id='editor" . $id . "' value='" . $row['end_time'] . " ' onchange='pruefung({currentid:" . $id . ",currentfieldname:\"end_time\"})'></input></td>";
            echo "<td class='luecke5'><input style='border:none; width:100%; background:rgba(0,0,0,0)' contenteditable='true' id='editor" . $id . "' value='" . $row['comments'] . " ' onchange='pruefung({currentid:" . $id . ",currentfieldname:\"comments\"})'></input></td>";
            echo "<td class='luecke6'><input style='border:none; width:100%; background:rgba(0,0,0,0)' contenteditable='true' id='editor" . $id . "' value='" . $row['total_time'] . " ' onchange='pruefung({currentid:" . $id . ",currentfieldname:\"total_time\"})'></input></td>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "No results!";
    }
    ?>

    <script>
        var oldValue;

        function pruefung(params) {
            var newValue = document.getElementById('editor' + params.currentid).value; //editor id verknüpfung falsch?
            if (oldValue == newValue) {
                console.log("no changes");
            } else {
                console.log("changes");
                $.ajax({
                    url: "update.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        value: newValue,
                        id: params.currentid,
                        fieldname: params.currentfieldname
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert("Saved successfully!");
                        document.location.reload(true);
                    },
                    error: function(data) {
                        alert("error: " + data);
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    </script>


</table>
```

Comment: What error you get?

Comment: @Jaymin no error message, it uploads the user_id everytime instad of something else..

Comment: So everytime you type something, the page gets refreshed and shows just user_id is it like that?

Comment: @Jaymin I have my columns, and everytime I write somethin in these interactive columns on the webpage and refresh it, the text in the column will be the same like user_id is

Comment: Do you pass the data with ajax or post it like normal webpage?

Comment: Please show where the actual database update happens. (Edit it into your question, not in comments, extended code snippets are hardly readable in there.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your AJAX call you have : `var newValue = document.getElementById('editor' + params.currentid).value;`

In your table, **for each** row you have : `id='editor" . $id . "'`. This is a **duplicate of ids**.

When doing `var newValue = document.getElementById('editor' + params.currentid).value;` You are getting the **first** element that has this id, that's why `newValue` is always the id (the first row holding the id value)

I suggest you to remove that `var newValue = ...` but instead insert the value in the object you pass as parameter of `pruefung()`, such as `onchange='pruefung({currentid:" . $id . ",currentfieldname:\"user_id\",value:\"" . $row['user_id'] . "\"})` for the id row, `onchange='pruefung({currentid:" . $id . ",currentfieldname:\"user_id\",value:\"" . $row['start_time'] . "\"})` for the start time row, and so on...

And then, in your AJAX call, replace `var newValue = document.getElementById(...)` by `var newValue = params.value`

Comment: You are welcome, remember that ids have to be unique :)